# SSRS - Find first occurrence within row group where condition holds and display value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I need to get the first value within a large data-set, based on a row group where the condition holds true.

I.e: Get the First Value Where Deal Name is "ABC" and Type = "main" within a row group (scope) of a entire dataset.

I tried the following:

```
=IIF(Fields!DealName.Value="ABC" AND Fields!Type.Value="Main", First(Fields!DealValue.Value, "Deal"), NOTHING)
```

There are 3 records with distinct values for Deal Values. 
In this scenario, it is picking up 0, when it should have picked up 4946.

Can I have the entire if statement in a scope?
Help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Add sample data in order to help you and expected results in order to help you.

Comment: maybe try using first outside of iif like =First(IIF(Fields!DealName.Value="ABC" AND Fields!Type.Value="Main", Fields!DealValue.Value, NOTHING), "Deal")

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, you want to get first value based on `if` condition. Then you can use `LookUp`

Lookup(1, IIF(Fields!DealName.Value="ABC" AND Fields!Type.Value="Main", 1, NOTHING), Fields!DealValue.Value, "DateSetName")